# GEM_PATH is looking in /usr/local/rvm/gems, which has been deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I  messed up my development environment while working on my rails app, so I attempted to completely remove rvm, rails and ruby from my system so I could start fresh. I then installed rbenv, ruby and rails.

Now I am getting the following error when i try to use the `rails s` command:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0.a) among 5 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

I am assuming this is because I removed the 'usr/local/rvm' folder, but it is still trying to look there. I'm thinking I need to change the GEM_PATH, but I'm not sure how. If anyone can help me, that would be great, I am totally lost.

Comment: Have you closed and reopened your terminal to get rid of rvm settings? If so, is there still anything about rvm in your dotfiles?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem reinstalling rails, I belive that my RVM was confuse, anyway first try to [config your terminal ubuntu](https://rvm.io/images/Title_and_Command.jpg) first and next reinstall

$ gem install rails

Comment: The question is about `GEM_PATH`, your answer does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: But fix the problem